I created a custom parameter to eventOrder but Fullcalendar separetes allDay from not allDay events
The problem I am trying to solve is to display all events (doesn't matter if allDay true or false) ordering by the parameter I created named 'level'.
I created a 'level' parameter for my EventObject in fullcalendar, but even if I use             eventOrder: "level", it seems that the events are separated in two sections (the 'allDay : true' are shown in the top and 'allDay : false' in the bottom).
I also tried combining other configurations as 'eventOrderStrict: true' and 'allDaySlot: false', but it didn't work.
Important: the project I am working implements the Fullcalendar component version 3.

I'd suggest that if you don't actually care about the start times and you just want all events to be ordered by your custom parameter instead, then don't pass any start times to fullCalendar and just mark all the events as allDay: true. That way there's nothing else for fullCalendar to use for ordering the events except for your level value.

@ADyson thanks for the answer but actually the start date should also be respected. I want to have some levels of "priority" and than list the events by the start date after, but I think the fullCalendar in the version 3 separates the allDay from the 'not allDay' events in two lists (and if that's correct, I would like to know if in version 6 it is different).

I said it might make sense to ignore the start times, not the dates. An allDay event still has a date.

I think the fullCalendar in the version 3 separates the allDay from the 'not allDay' events in two lists...that depends on which View you are using (and in that respect, no, nothing has really changed in version 6. The eventOrder functionality is different in v6 though.)

OK, I think I got your suggestion now:
I could consider every event as allDay events and only consider the finishing date, right?
In this case, I wouldn't have the starting date showing in the event card. Is that correct? I am asking this because now I started considering an event that I want to show in the section of the "allDay = false" events which are not considered "allDay" in my system but their starting and finishing date are same with 00:00 hour and when I pass the allDay as false the hour is shown as 00:00 (not expected and I am trying to modify this behavior to not show any hour).

about "The eventOrder functionality is different in v6 though.", do you know if it is possible to consider allDay = true and allDay = false in the "same section" and order them with a customized parameter as "level"?

When you say "same section", are you referring to the fact that the Agenda/TimeGrid view has a separate all-day section? As I said above, the functionality you get depends on which view you use. In all versions, as far as I know, if you use a time-aware view then there is a separate section for all Day events, and also, the non-all-day events have to be placed on the grid next to their start time, no matter what - otherwise the time grid would make no sense. So, logically, an eventOrder setting can't override the start time in a time-aware view - hence the suggestion in my first comment

Either that or maybe you should use a non-time-aware view for this purpose, such as month, or list, or the basic view

Hey ADyson I am trying to do an adjust in an existing project and I don't have 100% what do you mean about time-aware view, but reading the documentation I am using the https://fullcalendar.io/docs/month-view so I guess it would be a time-aware example of view.
The point is that I have some allDay events that should appear before the time-specific events in the vertical list (events such as holidays, birhtdays) and other events that "start" at 00:00 and "end" at 00:00 of same day that are "tasks" that can be done at anytime of the day, so they should appear after the specific-time tasks.

To achieve this behavior I created a "level" parameter and it worked well for the allDay events that I want to show at the top (holidays with level = 1 and birthdays with level = 2), but I can't adjust the behavior of those tasks with non-specific hour to be done... if I consider them allDay = true, they will appear before the specific-time tasks no matter what (even if I use the parameter "level = 999" for example). What I am trying to do now is consider them "allDay = false" but I got the start hour showing in the calendar with 00:00 and also they are shown before because of the first hour.

I am using the fullcalendar.io/docs/month-view so I guess it would be a time-aware example of view...no, that isn't a time-aware view, because it only has dates on it, not times of day. Agenda (or timeGrid in v6) is a time-aware view because it shows times of day (as well as dates), and aligns events with those times in the display

Month view doesn't have a separate "allDay" section, but agenda/timeGrid does, so that's why I thought you were using that view.

OK, I see! We have 3 views being: month, week and day. Each of them with the same behavior, a specific cell for each day and a vertical list with the events.
I found something related to this in the code about week and day views:
views: {
day: {
titleFormat: 'D MMMM YYYY',
columnHeaderFormat: 'ddd',
},
week: {
titleFormat: 'D MMMM YYYY',
titleRangeSeparator: ' até ',
columnHeaderFormat: 'ddd D/M',
}
},

"month" view is this: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/XWwYbva?editable=true&editors=001

"agenda" view is this: (however many days it shows is irrelevant, it's still an "agenda" view) https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/xxNzwOz?editable=true&editors=001

We have 3 views being: month, week and day. Each of them with the same behavior, a specific cell for each day and a vertical list ...that sounds like maybe it's the list view - https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/list-view, with 3 different view durations provided? ?? You can tell what view it is by looking at the fullCalendar code in your page - it will show it in the header button config, and/or in the defaultView option.

In that case my demo would look like this: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/XWwYbva?editable=true&editors=001 . Again there are no separate sections for all-day events in this view type.

The point is that I have some allDay events that should appear before the time-specific events in the vertical list (events such as holidays, birhtdays) and other events that "start" at 00:00 and "end" at 00:00 of same day that are "tasks" that can be done at anytime of the day, so they should appear after the specific-time tasks...if they can be done at any time of day, then why aren't they just classed as "allDay" events? I appreciate possible they don't take all day to complete, but equally they don't have a specific time associated with them, so setting them at 00:00 isn't true.

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/eventOrder clearly states that it only takes the eventOrder parameter into consideration for events which "have the same exact start time and duration". An all-day event won't have the same duration as a timed event - therefore, eventOrder has no effect.

FullCalendar 6 however doesn't have this restriction - eventOrder can override other rules... demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/BaeVodj . See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v6/eventOrder

Hey ADyson I found the type of view in ther header as you suggested.             header: {
left: 'prev,next today',
center: 'title',
right: 'basicDay,basicWeek,month'
},
in this case, as I use the basicDay, basicWeek and month views, I guess I am not using any time-aware type of view as you suggested and considering what you meant about the documentation, the eventOrder just won't work in v3 for the specific-time events (since they don't have the same exact start time and duration), but the v6 would work (thanks for the demo).

the problem is that we were not planning to update the version of fullcalendar component in the project right now (what would solve the business demand). regard your question about "why aren't they just classed as "allDay" events?": those events are current being considered as allDay in the production code, I was just trying to show them after the specific-time events. In a nutshell, our clients want to see some allDay events, such as holidays and birthdays, before the specific-time events. The other "allDay" events should appear in the end of the list, since they're "less important/urgent".

Ok I see. Unfortunately I don't think you can do that without upgrading fullCalendar

I really appreciate your help ADyson! The demos in the codepen.io really helped me understand and demonstrate to my colleagues the problem. As I am new to the community, I am feeling very well received. In this case we may update the version instead of creating workarounds, will see! Later I will post the result here! Big thanks again.

No problem. In future though please try to state all the considerations at the start in the question so it doesn't take lots of follow up questions to understand the full scenario. And include some relevant data and a proper code sample, so we can see exactly what you mean :-). You may find the [ask] guide and its linked articles useful. Welcome to stackoverflow
